# How to refresh a JavaFX ListView of CheckBoxes and keep their CheckedProperty?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, checkbox, refresh

How can I refresh this `JFXListView` when the List `R.OffrirService()` changes and keep the `checked` property of `JFXCheckBox`es?

This is my code:

```
@FXML
private JFXListView li_se;

int d;

@FXML
private void Services(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        li_se.getItems().clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < R.OffrirService().size(); i++) {
            JFXCheckBox s = new JFXCheckBox(R.OffrirService().get(i));
            s.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasOn, isNowOn) -> {
                if (wasOn == false) {
                    try {
                        //if checked do something
                        d++;
                        if (d == R.OffrirService().size()) {
                            //if all checked do something
                        }
                    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ParticipantController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                } else {
                    //if unchecked do something
                    d--;
                    if (d == 0) {
                        //if all unchecked do something
                    }
                }
                //System.out.println(s.getText() + " changed on state from " + wasOn + " to " + isNowOn);
            });
            li_se.getItems().add(s);
        }
     } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ParticipantController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't even compile since when registering the listener the number of `{` does not match the number of `}` in the lambda.

Comment: Sorry about that i just i just corrected the code. you can replace the remote ArrayList R.OffrirService() by a local one.

Comment: Have you got a solution ?